# What is the difference between a "source folder" and a "pydev package" in PyDev Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, package, pydev

What is the difference between a "source folder" and a "pydev package" in PyDev Eclipse?

[image: Menu options for creating new item in PyDev]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A "source folder" is a directory that contains source files. Putting .py files into this directory will make them discoverable by PyDev, so that you can for instance import them from other Python files.

A "PyDev Package" is a Python package. This means that it contains a file called `__init__.py`. For example, if you create a new PyDev Package with name `foo`, then you will get file `foo/__init__.py`. You can place other .py files into `foo/`, which you can then import. So, if you place `bar.py` into `foo/`, then you can do

```
import foo.bar
```

This is not possible with source folders.

You normally place packages into source folders. I don't know if it is possible to place a source folder into a package, but even if it were you would hardly ever do it.

Comment: does source folder have to include a `__init__.py` so that interpreter can find modules in this folder?

Comment: No - that's what packages are for. :)

Comment: then "source folder" is better, it does the same thing and doesnt need a `__init__.py` file. right?

Comment: Depends on what you want - In the above example, you can ``import foo.bar`` because ``foo`` is a package. If foo were a mere source folder, this would not be possible. Source folders *contain* packages, and I don't think it's possible for a package to contain a source folder.

Comment: Updated my answer with the information from my previous comment.

Comment: but if `foo` is a source folder and `bar` is in it, i would just need `import bar`. right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36584/discussion-between-michael-herrmann-and-alwbtc)

Answer (score 13):

a **package** is a collector for files that have a logical grouping

```
import <package>.<file>
```

and a **source folder** makes the files directly importable

```
import <file>
```

and the **regular folder** is basically inaccessible.

I made a quick project that shows the differences.  I put one file in each type of container: **regular folder**, **package**, and **source folder**.  Each file had two items:
a function called show()
and a class with a single public member show()

[image]

I then put a driver file at the top level (in the project root, next to the 3 containers).  This was just to try the different ways of importing things.  Here is a copy of that driver file with comments to describe how the different elements are used:

```
### valid imports
import package
import package.file_in_package as thefileinpackage
import file_in_source

### invalid imports
#import package.file_in_package.packageclass   #runtime ImportError
#import file_in_package                        #unresolved import

#import source                                 #unresolved import
#import source.file_in_source                  #unresolved import
#import file_in_source.sourceclass             #runtime ImportError

#import folder                                 #unresolved import
#import file_in_folder                         #unresolved import
#import folder.file_in_folder                  #unresolved import

thefileinpackage.show()
packageclasss_inst = thefileinpackage.packageclass()
packageclasss_inst.show()

file_in_source.show()
sourceclass_inst = file_in_source.sourceclass()
sourceclass_inst.show()

package.file_in_package.show()
packageclass_inst2 = package.file_in_package.packageclass()
packageclass_inst2.show()
```

Comment: So source folder make modules directly "under classpath", expressed in Java way, while package in python is like package in Java.

Answer (score 2):

A source folder is the folder which is added to the PYTHONPATH.

A package is a folder which has an `__init__.py` file (and which is located beneath a source folder).